# Is there anyway I can achieve something like a new thread in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So basically is there a way in CodeIgniter to make asynchronous action?

For example, upon registration I want to send out e-mail. This tends to take a second or two, and the user has to wait a noticeable amount of time.

So is there a way in CodeIgniter or PHP to initiate the sending of email (or whatever other action), and continue on the execution of script without waiting for it to end?

The only thing I can think of is making it in a way that maybbe some cron executes that action independently of that script. But is there anything I can do within script?

Comment: Calling the controller action that sends the email as an asynchronous AJAX request is probably the best solution. That would be a non blocking call in the browser, which would allow the user to do other things.

Comment: What happens if I fire off an ajax request, and user reloads the page before getting a reply? Is that even possible, or any AJAX request has to complete before page can be reloaded?

Comment: This largely depends on if you run on windows or linux it's possible on both.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add an entry to a message queue like rabbit mq or zero mq, which allows you to process that message asynchronously later on. Taking a look at react-php might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

How about an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) Request?

You can send requests to your server asynchronously and have them triggered by anything you want. Once the function executes and the request is made to the server, regardless of whether or not the user leaves the page, the process will continue on the server.

For example:

```
$('#submit-btn').on( "click", function() {

   function signUp(){
   var email = $('#subscription').val();
   var op1 = $('#option1').val();
   var op2 = $('#option2').val();

   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('email', email);
   formData.append('option_1', op1);
   formData.append('option_2', op2);      

   $.ajax({
        url: '/subscribe',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST'
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do in CI,

Create a copy of index.php, move it above the webroot, ie. where it is not accessible in the browser.  In this index file - where it says `DEFAULT CONTROLLER` add this line

```
$routing['controller'] = 'cli';
```

This will lock or jail that index.php file to only use the `cli.php` file in controllers, that way users on the web cant initiate this controllers methods. This is important for security reasons.  There are some other benefits too, it gives you a separate environment in CI for your background scripts. For example you can set `defined('ENVIRONMENT')` separate of your site, etc.

in `cli.php` add something like this

```
/**
 * 
 * <pre>
 *  <b>Windows</b>
 *          php -f "{path to index}/index.php" "[arg1]/[arg2]" 
 *  <b>Linux</b>
 *          /usr/bin/php -f "{path to index}/index.php" "[arg1]/[arg2]"
 */
public function index(){
    echo __METHOD__ . "/n";
    print_r(func_get_args());
}
```

The comments are the command line call to use.  Or you can use my BgProcess class

Create this class

```
class BgProcess{
    /**
     * 
     * @param string $arg0, $arg1 ...
     * $arg0 is location of php file to run
     * $arg1 ..is additional params to send to script
     */
    public function __construct($arg0){
        if(stripos(php_uname('s'), 'win') > -1){
            $_osWin = true;
        }else{
            $_osWin = false;
        }

        $args = func_get_args();
        $file = str_replace('\\', '/', array_shift($args));
        $script = escapeshellarg($file).' '.escapeshellarg(implode('/', $args));
        if(false !== ($phpPath = $this->_getPHPExecutableFromPath($_osWin))){
            if($_osWin){    
                $WshShell = new \COM('WScript.Shell');
                $cmd = 'cmd /C '.$phpPath.' '.$script;
                $oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0, false);
            }else{
                //> /dev/null &
                $cmd = $phpPath.' -f '.$script.' > /dev/null &';
                exec($cmd);
            }
        }else{
            die('Could not find php executable');
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return string|boolean
     */
    protected function _getPHPExecutableFromPath($_osWin) {
        $paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, getenv('PATH'));
        if($_osWin){
            foreach ($paths as $path) {
                if (strstr($path, 'php')){
                    $php_executable =  $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'php.exe';
                    if(file_exists($php_executable) && is_file($php_executable)){
                        return $php_executable;
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            foreach ($paths as $path) {
                $php_executable = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "php";
                if (file_exists($php_executable) && is_file($php_executable)) {
                    return $php_executable;
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call it like this

```
  $BG = new BgProcess("{path to index }index.php, $arg1, $arg2 .. etc );
```

Add your code to cli as you would normally in a controller. If not using index method call it like this.

```
  php -f "{path to index}/index.php" "[method]/[arg2]" 


  $BG = new BgProcess("{path to index }index.php, $method, $arg1 .. etc );
```

Essentially when you call it with the command line or with the BgProcess class it routes just like normal CI class, there are some differences on `$_SERVER` variables and things because you are running in the command line interface.  But it's the "proper" way to do it.

This is stripped down from what I have setup so not sure it will work right off, but it should get you started.  RabbitMq for this is a bit overkill, when all you need is a background process.  By the way this is a tiny part of my RabbitMq setup. Rabbit is awesome if you need a full blown queuing system, but there is the installation of it and learning curve with what client to use etc..

Please note you need to be able to use the `run` or `exec` commands in php.  Also never put user input in the arguments of shell commands, that's the main reason for moving the index file out of the web accessible location.  Only call this using properly validated input.  I do have `escapeshellarg` to clean the input, but I wouldn't rely only on that.

By the way this was several days worth of research to run a proper background process on windows.

As others mentioned you can do it easier with Ajax, but you have the overhead of using the httpd server.  This would be similar to running it with a cron, but without the cron.  If you are familiar with that the command line call should look pretty similar to the cron call, unless you use curl for that which is `yuck`.

Cheers!